# Sync a wordpress site with git

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

With WordPress, what is the best way to sync a local test server with a staging server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with git and assumes that you have already set up a repository with GitHub etc.

This assumes you are using Linux or OSX.

1) Download  [this php script](https://github.com/dangreenisrael/SyncWordpress/blob/master/dumpsite.php)  and store it somewhere on your local machine.

2) Put this into your local machine's `~/.bash_profile`

`push-wordpress() { php SCRIPT_LOCATION/dumpsite.php tshirt_wp LOCAL_URL REMOTE_URL DUMP_LOCATION ; cd LOCAL_REPO_DIRECTORY; git commit -a -m 'Database Updated'; git push origin master; }`

3) Put this into your remote machine's `~/.bash_profile`

`pull-wordpress() { cd REMOTE_REPO_DIRECTORY; git stash; git pull; chmod -R 755 REMOTE_REPO_DIRECTORY*; mysql -u DB_USERNAME --password=DB_PASSWORD DB_NAME < backup-DB_NAME.sql; }`

4) On your local machine, run `push-wordpress`

5) On your remote machine, run `pull-wordress`

It should work 'out of the box' but it may take some tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Dan's script is working for me with a few modifications:

1. The PHP script was giving me errors at mysql_connect() so I had to make the following insert at line 14: `$host = "localhost:3306"; $user = "root"; $pass = "root";`, which are the default settings for MAMP.
2. the bash profile should read `push-wordpress() { php SCRIPT_LOCATION/dumpsite.php DB_NAME LOCAL_URL REMOTE_URL DUMP_LOCATION ; cd LOCAL_REPO_DIRECTORY; git commit -a -m 'Database Updated'; git push origin master; }`.  The first time you run it, it will not add the dumped database, and you will need to either manually run a `git add .` and commit again, or add `git add . ;` before the git commit in the bash script.

Comment: Never got your script to output a sql file, however. It outputs and empty file. I'm unfamiliar with PHP so re-writing this as a bash script using wp-cli.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I deduce that you have three servers

1. Local development
2. Staging server
3. Production server

My workflow is: install WordPress on all three, install the required WP plugins and clean away the unneeded pre-installed wordpress stuff. The only folder under source control is than the `wp-content/themes/my-awesome-theme` folder or the child-theme folder. After ready installing, clone the `my-awesome-theme` repo in the `wp-content/themes` folder.

### Rationale

WordPress is not under source control. Theme development is. Just like the database, the `wp-content/media` folder also should not be under source control as they either cannot be source controlled or do not contain source files.

Most editors are fine with a sub folder under sc and will find the repo. If not, I've learned that, for instance in vscode, opening and closing a file in the theme folder hints the extension to start watching the folder.

### Additional

What I also do normally is update the `wp-config.php` to work on the three difference locations somewhere after the WP_DEBUG define include:

```php
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://my-awesome-site.local' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://my-awesome-site.local' );
```

And on stage/prod something like;

```php
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://my-awesome-site.tld' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://my-awesome-site.tld' );
```

to prevent these from looked up in the database. You might have to do the same with the database connection setup further up.

### Database select

To have different database settings for each of these versions use the name that was used to access the site. In `wp_config.php` change this:

```php
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    default: /* production */
        define( 'DB_NAME',     'server-db-name');
        define( 'DB_USER',     'server-dbuser-name');
        define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'server-dbuser-pass');
        break;
    case 'stage.my-awesome-site.tld':
        define( 'DB_NAME',     'stage-db-name');
        define( 'DB_USER',     'stage-dbuser-name');
        define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'stage-dbuser-pass');
        break;
    case 'my-awesome-site.local':
        define( 'DB_NAME',     'local-db-name');
        define( 'DB_USER',     'local-dbuser-name');
        define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'local-dbuser-pass');
        break;
}


/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

If using PHP 8.x you could use some fancy `match() {}` construct.

Alternatively you want to keep the db config nice and tidy in one easy location you could settle with a `parse_ini_file()` construct:

```php
$ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$settings = parse_ini_file($ROOT.'/db.conf', true);
define( 'DB_NAME',     $settings['db']['name'] );
define( 'DB_USER',     $settings['db']['user'] );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', $settings['db']['passwort'] );
define( 'DB_HOST',     $settings['db']['server'];
```

with this `db.conf` file:

```
[db]
server = localhost
name = db_name
user = db_user
passwort = 'db_password'
```

Make sure db.conf is made not accessible with a .htaccess (!). it would cause an extra file opening performance hit (probably negligible with all the magic WP is doing).

### Notes

Including the whole WordPress folder in SC and then manually gitignore the one's I *don't* need sounds like the wrong way around. And probably is not future proof; who knows what the WordPress developers add to the installation.