# Using Wordpress with Git - which files should I ignore?

Tags: wordpress, git

For the past 6 or so months I have been working on **Laravel** projects that are closer to web apps rather than full, content managed sites.

Recently I've started a **Wordpress** project and there's something that baffles me, how do you use `Git` with WordPress?

I ask because in Laravel you can basically push everything asides from `node_modules`, `storage` and the composer `vendor` folder.

I have also read that it is not a good idea to store `wp-config` in your repository, it's a strange one as Laravel uses an `.env` file to similar effect.

I found the following **.gitignore**

```
*.log
wp-config.php
wp-content/advanced-cache.php
wp-content/backup-db/
wp-content/backups/
wp-content/blogs.dir/
wp-content/cache/
wp-content/upgrade/
wp-content/uploads/
wp-content/mu-plugins/
wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
wp-content/plugins/hello.php
/.htaccess
/license.txt
/readme.html
/sitemap.xml
/sitemap.xml.gz
```

Comment: Please revise to ask something more specific. If you're wondering which files should be ignored, ask that (in the title as well).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel's `.env` file contains sensitive data just as WP's `wp-config.php` so we don't usually push it into the repo.

As to how I use Git with WordPress:

- I exclude the `wp-config.php` file, the developer cloning the repo doesn't need it anyways: they can fill in the credentials themselves when working on the project on their local development environment. Another good reason to leave this file out is you don't want to expose your site's details (host, database name, username, password, salts, etc) to the world.
- I exclude the `uploads` folder. The reason is that while developing we usually add dummy images to our posts and pages, images that won't be used at all when the site is finally ready for production so there's no reason to "pollute" the repo with these.

One of the things I love about Laravel is that database changes can also be tracked thanks to *migrations*. WordPress, on the other hand, doesn't have anything like that so you'll have to find a plugin (or some other mean) to keep your local database in sync with the staging one.

---

**Update:**

Since you updated your question to ask which files should be specifically excluded from the Git repo, I think the ones you posted from that `.gitignore` file you found are good enough. I don't see the need to ignore the `readme.txt` file though but that won't do any harm either.

Comment: Do you yourself use WordPress or Laravel? I think I got too comfortable with the Laravel ecosystem

Comment: @JesseOrange I use both, actually. Been doing WordPress stuff for the past 12 years now. I started using Laravel around two years ago I think. I totally get why you got comfortable with it, it's so easy to use and to customize! I have never mixed both frameworks in a single project though (that would be an atrocity haha).

Comment: Have you worked on a Wordpress site with multiple developers? I literally came off of Laravel and realized how much the framework actually bakes in for you.

Comment: Yes, I have. WordPress is quite versatile as well, and there's a great community behind it too.

Comment: So, in summary am I safe to just push the whole thing to Git?

Comment: Assuming you're using the .gitignore file from your question, yes.

Comment: What about wp-admin, wp-include, wp-content/* (!wp-content/themes)? They don;t make much sense on a git repo, do they?

Comment: No, they don't IMO @theking2 (but I've seen -and worked with- dev teams track them so it depends on the agreed workflow and internal practices.)

Comment: See my notes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996999/sync-a-wordpress-site-with-git

Answer (score 8):

You can ignore almost everything with the following exceptions:

1. wp-content/themes/my-theme (your theme and/or child theme)
2. wp-content/plugins/my-custom-plugin. (any custom plugins you create)

Additionally, I have found two very good sources for gitignore files for WordPress. The first which is very straightforward is on [gitignore.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20110808211057/http://gitignore.org/) and the second which is extremely surgical  is by Sal Ferrarello and can be found here: https://salferrarello.com/wordpress-gitignore/

Just modify as required and of course, avoid the config.php. It has install specific info such as your database host & login which you may not want to expose to prying eyes.

Comment: Why just custom plugins? Why use version control if you can't use it to rollback bad core or plugin updates?

Comment: @HashimAziz Same question + it helps keep track of any changes made to the plugin directly which is not how it should be. Just for tracking bad code changes.

Comment: @simlpymarkb: You're first link was haijacked. You might like to update that.

Comment: @HashimAziz do you mean your own plugins? For reusabilty these should go in their own repo any way. Third party plugins should not pollute your git history.

Comment: @theking2 For what reason shouldn't they "pollute" git history? Why do you consider it a pollution to be able to use version control to keep track of and rollback unauthorised changes to your site's third-party plugins in addition to Wordpress core? This is something I'm constantly in two minds about, but I believe my and *m4no*'s points for why plugins *should* be committed are good ones, and I've yet to see any good ones for why they *shouldn't*.

Comment: Plugins probably (hopefully) are multipurpose and not specific to a certain website. I would put the theme folder in a repo and create a repo for each plugin source. the compiled versions of plugins are assembled in a specific website..

Comment: @HashimAziz having said that. Of course there might be a non- multipurpose plugin linked to the site. For instance one that declares user defined post types. You migh be right. Still it seems not future proof to exclude specific folders. It would make more sense to _include_ the `wp-content/thems/theme-name` and the specific `wp-content/plugin/...` folders. Large media files probably will not need version control.